# Existence of smallest $\delta>0$ for a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

There's something on my textbook that I don't understand:

> Let $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on the interval $I$.So
>
> $\forall x_0$ $\epsilon$ $I$ and $\forall \epsilon>0$ there $\exists \delta>0$ such that $\forall x$ $\epsilon$ $I$
>
> $|x-x_0|<\delta$ $\implies$ $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$
>
> It is obvious that in the definition above $\delta$ depends on
>   $\epsilon$ and the point $x_0$ . If the interval $I$ is finite , then
>   let $\delta_0>0$ be the smallest of all numbers $\delta>0$ such that
>   :
>
> $\forall x_0$ $\epsilon$ $I$ and $\forall x$ $\epsilon $ $I$ such that
>   $|x-x_0|<\delta_0$ $\implies$ $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$

Up to this everything is clear.But then it states that:

> If the interval $I$ is infinite , then the number $\delta_0>0$ doesn't
>   always exist.

And then gives the definition of uniform continuity . I don't understand why in the second case the existence of the number $\delta_0>0$ is not assured,as I could understand it means that there can be cases when the smallest number $\delta>0$ with the property as mentioned above can not exist.How is this possible ? If anyone could give me an answer or a hint I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: **HINT**: Consider $f(x)=1/x$ on $(0,1]$. Fix your $\epsilon>0$. What must happen with $\delta$ as $x$ gets closer and closer to $0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin it will get smaller and smaller right?

Comment: @TedShifrin yet the interval $(0,1]$ is not infinite . Am I right?

Comment: Yes, as $x\to 0^+$, $\delta(x)\to 0$. ... Whether the interval is infinite isn't relevant; it's whether it's a closed interval or not. If you want to see the same problem on $[0,\infty)$, look at $f(x)=x^2$. It's just a bit trickier to do the algebra.

Comment: Then why is it written on my book finite interval and not closed is it the same thing as being closed and finite?

Comment: That sounds very wrong. You'd have to quote me the entire context, though.

Comment: Despite "up to this everything is clear", I think the material preceding this remark is confused. If, for some $x_0$ and $\varepsilon$, a certain $\delta>0$ works in the definition of continuity, then, for that $x_0$ and $\varepsilon$, every small positive value for $\delta$ would work equally well. So "the smallest" such $\delta$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AndreasBlass so why then it is written like that in my book.Now I'm much more confused about it !

Comment: Hard to know when you don't tell us which book it is and you don't quote the entire text